# how to make strategy have a alert (with sound) in pine script (trading view)

Tags: pine-script

I am using a simple strategy in pine script,
she have a visual alert but have not a alert with sound, 
can't found it in the alarm as well
how to make it beep?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about alert for strategy that this feature is not implemented yet. But it will available soon.

Comment: Any update on this.

Comment: Alert for strategy was implemented https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/strategy-alerts-are-live-now-18770/